# Writing to module-wide variable

Tags: python

Lets say I have these 3 (tiny) python files -

**a.py**

```
myvar = 'a'
```

**b.py**

```
import a
import c

myvar = 'b'
c.pr()
```

**c.py**

```
from a import myvar

def pr():
    print myvar
```

Now if I execute `b.py` I get output

```
a
```

But I really want output to be as

```
b
```

So please tell me how can I restructure/modify the programs so that the *module-wide* `myvar` can be assigned a different value.

Comment: This is obviously confusing, so you want to avoid doing this sort of then when *at all possible*. (People provide below ways to do it; just keep in mind just because you can't doesn't mean you should.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **b.py**, you are setting **b.py**'s myvar. You want to access a's value of myvar. So **b.py** might look like:

```
import a
import c

a.myvar = 'b' # belongs to a
myvar = 'something different' # belongs to b
c.pr()
```

And you need to update **c.py** so that it uses **a.py**'s myvar, not it's own local copy. So **c.py**:

```
import a

def pr():
    print a.myvar
```

**Why?**

In your original **c.py**, when you call `from a import myvar`, this is equivalent to:

```
import a
myvar = a.myvar
```

This makes a local version of `myvar` in **c.py** upon import. If this is confusing, I found this [article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) about how python variables work very informative.

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it by having a fourth module `d.py`.

This module is imported by 'a', 'b', & 'c'.

As in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules):

> The canonical way to share information across modules within a single
>   program is to create a special module (often called config or cfg).
>   Just import the config module in all modules of your application; the
>   module then becomes available as a global name. Because there is only
>   one instance of each module, any changes made to the module object get
>   reflected everywhere

Just be careful; Once you've created this config module because it was necessary, it's easy to get carried away and start adding other variables to it just because it's there.  Most of the time there is a better way...