# What is the best way to have a flag that is shared by different modules in python?

Tags: python

> NOTE:  I am not setting different variables with the same name,
>   subclassing; these are all separated modules that uses the same
>   parameter. For sake of clarity I called it here in the same way. So
>   the question linked here is not related to my case.

I would like to set a specific flag for more than one module and class.

I have cases where the analysis on a process is done in local lab, while in others it has to be performed in a remote lab.

In each class and module of our system, I have a function that pass this parameter; which means that every time that we have to perform a set of analysis on a different location, I have to change a bunch of functions in different class and different modules.

```
Module1

analyzeAlpha("lab_a", compound, type)

Module2

analyzeSpect("lab_a", compound, type)
analyzePhot("lab_a", compound, type)

....moduleN
```

Now I would like to set this parameter in one place, so I can point each module to this location and they can load it and set the variable correctly...the problem is that I am not sure what would be the best way.

I thought about creating a class that each module would import; which has one parameter that is either True or False (or give numbers, in case that we  will have more location. The module would contain only one class; so I can set there the paramter and it will propagate to all the modules and functions. Not sure if this makes sense in python.

```
Module_labs:

class lab_location(object):
    lab_var = "lab_a"   

Module1

from Module_labs import lab_location
analyzeAlpha(lab_location.lab_var,compound, type)

....
```

Another way is to use a file to read; a function read it, and set the value; the modules import the function and get the value; although this means that each module has to call this function, which seems incredibly inefficient to me.

What would be the more efficient and pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: What about defining a constant in a module ?

Comment: You don't even need the class, just have a `parameters.py` file that simply defines `LAB_VAR = 'lab_a'`, then you can `import parameters` everywhere it's needed and use `parameters.LAB_VAR` or `from parameters import LAB_VAR` and use `LAB_VAR` directly.

Comment: Another option is to put it into an [environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ). Eg, (in Bash) `labname='lab_a' python -c "import os;print(os.environ['labname'])"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing to module-wide variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058350/writing-to-module-wide-variable)

Comment: Thanks for your replies; so I have the choice between a constant in a module, and import it in my modules, or a module that just hold that parameter, and import the module. I did check the other question, but I do not believe that it is a duplicate: I am not setting a variable in different places...it is the same; just trying to change all of them at once.

Comment: @newbiez: I agree that your question isn't a dupe of the one that SiHa linked. Using a module to hold configuration data is a fairly common Python practice, but to me it seems like overkill to have a module for a single string.